# Close elapsed time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I use **collectionView** to display **time** and **price**. Now it looks like this.
[image: iphone screenshot]

Me need close **elapsed time.** For example in screenShot time is **14:51**, me need to **close** and **fill** color elapsed time (grey color) the time before **14:00**. It's from **1:00** to **13:00**.

For load price and time I use backend and firestore in `func getDataFromBackend()`

It's my code:

```
class BookTimeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var priceTime: [PriceTime] = []
    let curTime = Date()

    lazy var hourTimeFormatter: DateFormatter = {

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH"
        return formatter

    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getDataFromBackend()

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return priceTime.count

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "timeCell", for: indexPath) as! BookTimeCell

        cell.timeLabel.text = "\(priceTime[indexPath.item].time):00"
        cell.priceLabel.text = "\(priceTime[indexPath.item].price) руб."

        return cell

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

    // I think on this i should close the time 

    }

    func getDataFromBackend() {

        MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)

        let newDate = dateFormatter.date(from: selectedDate)
        let dateForURL = dateTimeFormatter.string(from: newDate!)

        let url = URL(string: "https:....")

        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        request.httpMethod = "GET" 

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

            if let err = error {

                print(err)

            } else {

                do {

                    if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any] {

                        if let prices = jsonResult["prices"] as? [[String: Int]]{

                            for price in prices {

                                self.priceTime.append(PriceTime(price))
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        self.collectionView.reloadData()

                        MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                    }

                } catch {

                    print("error")
                }
            }
        })

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do it in `cellForItemAt:` method. Also need to set a timer for every minute and reload the `collectionView`.

Comment: @TheTiger How to do it? please tell me

Comment: Convert the time into `Date` object and you also have current time in date object `(Date())` then check `(if dateTime < Date())` close it.

Comment: Also show what `priceTime.time` contains, I want to see the time format.

Comment: `price.time` it's `Int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its suppose your `price.time` is an `Int` so that `10` etc. You can't compare time only so append Today's date string in this time.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
let now = Date()
let todayDateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: now)
let priceTime = todayDateStr + " \(19):00"
print(priceTime)
```

> Output: 04-05-2018 19:00

Now make a date object from this dateString.

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
if let priceTimeDateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: priceTime) {
    if priceTimeDateObj < now {
        print("Close this")
    }
}
```

**Or a more simple way you can convert both time into seconds and compare.**

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH"
let hours = Int(dateFormatter.string(from: now)) ?? 0
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm"
let minutes = Int(dateFormatter.string(from: now)) ?? 0

/// This is current time in seconds for today. Example: 18:24 = 66240
let seconds = (hours * 60 * 60) + (minutes * 60) 

let priceTimeSeconds = (priceItem.time * 60 * 60)
if  priceTimeSeconds < seconds {
    print("Close this")
}
```